# Apache2 .htaccess, multiple login dialogs

Tags: java, apache, .htaccess, servlets

I have following problem: I have a Java App running on my Apache2 / tomcat server.
The App has access restriction which is realized over .htaccess, the whole App folder is protected.

However there is a servlet in a subfolder which should be accessible with a separater user account, thus I changed the the config so that the **admin** account can access the whole App folder and the **guest** account the specific sub-folder which contains the servlet.

Furthermore, the servlet returns a HTML page, which accesses some images and CSS files from other folders, hence also these should be accessible by guest. (guest is a member of .htgroup car_projectGroup like some other user next to admin)

I realized this with following .htaccess config file, but there is some annoying problem: when I call the servlet with IE for each protected file which is linked from the returning HTML a new login pop-up appears and I have to re-enter the credentials. Using Chrome its better, there are just 2 login pop-ups, but still..

Is there a fix for that problem or another solution which might work?

```
Alias /projects/car_project /var/projects/car_project

<Directory /var/projects/car_project>
  AllowOverride All
  AuthType      Basic
  AuthName      "Car project Login"
  AuthUserFile  /var/projects/conf/.htusers
  AuthGroupFile /dev/null
  Require       user admin
  Order         allow,deny
  Allow from all
  DirectoryIndex index.jsp index.html
</Directory>

<Directory /var/projects/car_project/upload>
  AllowOverride All
  AuthType      Basic
  AuthName      "carprojectGroup (incl. guest) Login"
  AuthUserFile  /var/projects/conf/.htusers
  AuthGroupFile /var/projects/conf/.htgroups
  Require     group car_projectGroup
  Order         allow,deny
  Allow from all
  DirectoryIndex index.jsp index.html
</Directory>


<Directory ~ "(/var/projects/car_project/ux)|(/var/projects/car_project/resources)|(/var/projects/car_project/dir_with_servlet)">
  AuthType      Basic
  AuthName      "carprojectGroup (incl. guest) Login"
  AuthUserFile  /var/projects/conf/.htusers
  AuthGroupFile /var/projects/conf/.htgroups
  Require     group car_projectGroup
  Order         allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```